# Does BIRT Support Sub-Total Columns?

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt

We're trying using BIRT to design a specific cross-tab report and are not having much luck. The data, a time series of values with some attributes has the following shape:

### Data

```
AttributeA,AttributeB,AttributeC,Date,Value
A1,B1,C1,Jan-1-2010,25
A1,B1,C2,Jan-1-2010,25
...
```

I've gone ahead and created a cube for the data source and grouped by all the attributes which works great, but I'm not sure if/how I can summarize by the date.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to produce:

### Report

```
            Jan Feb Mar  Q1 Apr
A1, B1, C1   25  25  25  75  33
        C2   25  25  25  75  33
        C3   25  25  25  75  33
  Subtotal:  75  75  75 225  99

    B2, C1   50  25  25  75  33
        C2   50  25  25  75  33
  Subtotal: 100  50  50 150  66

A2, B1, C1   25  25  25  75  33
        C2   25  25  25  75  33
```

As you can see, I want my values summed by month in the first three months, then I want a Q1 sum, and so on. Is this kind of thing possible with BIRT, short of writing a bunchof Javascript?  If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your date attribute is recognised as a date by BIRT (instead of a string, for example), it should be relatively straightforward to add subtotals by quarter:

1. Edit the date dimension in the Cross Tab Cube Builder (by
   right-clicking on the Group in the Data Explorer and selecting
   Edit).
2. Select the date Group in the Groups and Summaries pane (on
   the right) and click the Edit button (to the right of the pane). In
   the Add/Edit Group Level dialog you should see a cascading set of
   date summarisation levels, with Month already checked. Check Quarter
   as well, and OK both the Add/Edit dialog and the Cross Tab Cube
   Builder.
3. Drag and drop the amended cube from the Data Explorer into the
   Layout designer. The new Cross Tab should include both quarter and
   month headings in the columns.
4. Select the Column Area tab in the
   Property editor of the Cross Tab. Click the Add... button (to the
   right of the empty Sub Totals list) and select Aggregate on:
   Group/Quarter. Click OK.
5. Preview the amended report. You will probably want to adjust the
   formatting.